# Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator. ERROR with VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the error I am getting when I launch my chrome with selenium chromedriver. After I click the ok button, my VBA script works normally. But I am getting this popup as:

"Could not load extension from C:\Windows\Temp\scoped_dir23880_1457\internal. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator."

I was able to launch chrome without this popup before and I tried to replace the chrome driver (2.44)compatible to my chrome (V 70.0) when I ran into this popup. But nothing seems to work.

After researching I was only able to find how to manage this issue in other languages except VBA. One constant solution I keep coming through is writing this piece of code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

How can I handle this case in VBA excel using selenium chrome driver? Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to load with an extension?  Also, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639 Perhaps,  driver.SetCapability "useAutomationExtension", False  though that is guessing.

Comment: Yeah with chromedriver 2.4. I don't mention any path in my script where that chromedriver.exe file is. I just check the reference selenium type library and it does the work for me.

Comment: Using this line (driver.SetCapability "useAutomationExtension", False) as you suggested in my script did not work for me. I am still getting the popup with that message.

Comment: Where is the popup launched form? Chrome? driver.AddArgument "--disable-notifications"

Comment: I believe this popup is thrown by the chrome because it cannot find the packaged extension from chromedriver.exe before starting the automation process. At runtime, ChromeDriver automatically places a .json and .js file at 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\scope_dirxxx\internal', which I assume are used to pack and add the extension 'Chrome Automation Extension 1' to the browser at runtime.